# How should I control tooltips in SVG files exported from Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, svg

I have drawn some diagrams in Visio that I want to export to SVG, to embed into a web page. Some elements of the diagrams will be hyperlinked (mainly callout text).  When I export the diagram to SVG format and view it in Chrome or Edge, I get tooltips/mouseover text on EVERY diagram element, showing shape names like 'Stop callout.10'.

**How can I remove these tooltips from the drawing elements that don't need them, and control what they say for those elements where a tooltip would be useful?**

I have tried the following:

- Adding 'ScreenTips' to elements in Visio.
- Setting Alt Text titles and descriptions in Visio's 'Format Shape' pane.
- Adding descriptions to hyperlinks for linked elements.
- Exporting the drawing with 'Include Visio data in the files' both ticked and unticked in the 'Save As' dialog.

When I examine the SVG source generated by Visio, I see that the tooltips that appear in the web browsers are contained in `<title>` elements under each group (`<g>`).  ScreenTip text never seems to appear in the exported SVG file.  Alt Text pulls through when the box is ticked to include Visio data, but appears inside a non-standard `<v:userDefs>` element which isn't rendered in my browsers.  Whether or not I choose to include Visio data, hyperlink descriptions appear in the SVG code, as `xlink:title` properties on the `<a>` elements.  However, they are not shown as tooltips; I just see a tooltip giving the random shape name from the `<title>` tag of the group inside the link.

I have found a couple of partial workarounds: if I rename a drawing element using the 'Shape Name' dialog on Visio's Developer ribbon, it will change the text of the tooltip I see in the SVG file.  However, I can't blank the names of shapes using this method, so I still get lots of shape name tooltips for things that don't need them.  I have also found that if I delete a `<title>` element from the SVG source, the relevant drawing element picks up a tooltip from the title of its parent element.  This can give some strange results, but at least means that I can reveal the titles of hyperlinks as tooltips for the drawing element with the link.  However, it also involves lots of manual editing of the SVG files, which I want to avoid.

Is there a proper way of getting meaningful SVG tooltips using Visio?  Or any way of telling it not to include the shape names at all?

I am using the desktop version of Visio: "Microsoft® Visio® Plan 2 MSO (Version 2208 Build 16.0.15601.20698) 32-bit", and rendering the SVG it produces using up-to-date versions of Chrome and Edge.